# Panda Dataframe - aggregate average by columns range

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have following data frame

```
ID    M1   M2   M3   D1   D2   
1     0,2  0,5  0,2  1    3  
2     0,1  0,4  1    4    6   
3     1    4    1    1    1
```

My goal is to create aggregated column average for each of the rows, grouping from M1 to M3, D1 to D2, expected output:

```
ID   M_avg    D_avg
1    0,3      2
2    0,5      5
3    2        1
```

I'm confused on how to do that.
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `ID` to index and for all another columns need numeric values:

```
df = df.set_index('ID').replace(',','.', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Then aggregate by columns names with [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)[`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) for remove numbers with `mean` and [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html):

```
df = (df.groupby(df.columns.str.extract('(\D+)', expand=False), axis=1)
        .mean()
        .add_suffix('_avg')
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   ID  D_avg  M_avg
0   1    2.0    0.3
1   2    5.0    0.5
2   3    1.0    2.0
```

Or use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df = df.set_index('ID').replace(',','.', regex=True).astype(float)

df = (df.groupby(df.columns.str.replace('\d+', '', regex=True), axis=1)
        .mean()
        .add_suffix('_avg')
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   ID  D_avg  M_avg
0   1    2.0    0.3
1   2    5.0    0.5
2   3    1.0    2.0
```

Comment: ``df.groupby(df.columns.str[0], axis = 1, sort = False)`` could be simpler

Comment: Hi, thx @sammywemmy. If I have several column with same name and I would like to group it? Shall I use columns.str()

Comment: then use `df.groupby(df.columns.str[:3], axis = 1, sort = False)` if need group by first 3 letters

Comment: thx @jezrael and for the entire column name?

Answer (score 0):

`df["M_avg"] = df.iloc[:,:3].mean(axis=1)`

`df["D_avg"] = df.iloc[:,3:5].mean(axis=1)`